# What species is The Doctor?

Tags: doctor-who

What species is the Doctor in *Doctor Who*?

Comment: I would recommend the "Peer Pressure" badge for this one ;)

Comment: He's a Time Lord. A Gallifreyan with a time machine (this is actually important) and extra lives. But that's not really what you wanted to know, right? Since that's stated in nearly every episode?

Comment: What do we do with this? Can we VTC it?

Comment: @Edlothiad I raised a VLQ flag and it was disputed. [This policy](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/689/what-sites-should-be-considered-general-references/690#690) (probably deprecated) on general reference says you can burninate the question; [this policy](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2400/should-we-burninate-general-reference) (more recent) says downvote it and close if too broad/opinion-based. Since this is neither we __1. downvote__ and __2. provide an answer to get the [Reversal](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges/50/reversal) badge__.

Comment: __Dear asker__! In case you're wondering about the down votes, you can look in the links in my previous comments. Shortly, the answer to this question is found in the first link when you type `the doctor` to any search engine. __No need to be alarmed__, though. You can cleanse your karma by getting the [Peer pressure](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges/20/peer-pressure) badge, and go on asking __good, on-topic__ questions. Take the [tour]!

Comment: Besides, everyone knows he's a hologram based on a human. #voyager #bestdoctor #photonsbefree

Answer (score 13):

Actually this is slightly harder to answer than you might think. Throughout the show (and reboot series) he's been described as being either a Timelord or, latterly, a Gallifreyan.

> **CHRISTINA:** *You look human.*
>
> **DOCTOR:** *You look Timelord. Anyway.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Planet of the Dead](http://www.chakoteya.net/DoctorWho/30-15.htm)</sup></sub>

and

> **MONARCH:** *[You are] An Earthling.*
>
> **DOCTOR:** ***A Gallifreyan.** Tegan is an Earthling, Adric is an Alzarian, and Nyssa there is from Traken.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Four to Doomsday](http://www.chakoteya.net/DoctorWho/19-2.htm)</sup></sub>

However, in the [1996 Doctor Who film](http://www.chakoteya.net/8Doctor/movie.htm), the Doctor was repeatedly confirmed to be half-human(!).

> **MASTER:** *Fascinating. See that? That's the retinal structure of the human eye. **The Doctor is half human!** No wonder.*

and

> **WAGG:** *Grace says you have a big secret. What is it?*
>
> **DOCTOR:** *I'm half human. On my mother's side.*

This fact could be easily dismissed as non-canon if it wasn't then confirmed in at least one other property; [The Infinity Doctors](http://garic-che.ru/Books/pda/pda_17.pdf)

> *The Doctor knew exactly who he was, who he’d always been. He was a
> Time Lord, from the Noble House of Lungbarrow on the planet Gallifrey.
> **He had been born of the Loom, son of the greatest explorer of his age
> and a human woman, Annalise… no… his mother’s name had been Penelope.**
> He knew his father’s name, at least: his father’s name wasn’t Ulysses*

---

Who Showrunner Russell T. Davies apparently wanted to retcon this (questionable) heritage out of existence, but ultimately chose not to do so out of respect for the film.

> *“I don’t like the half human thing. **He certainly isn’t half human,** but
> it’s less interesting to say it simply doesn’t count. I always wanted
> to put in a line where someone says to the Doctor, ‘Are you human?’
> And the Doctor says, ‘No, but I was once in 1999. It was a 24-hour
> bunk.’ Part of the reason I never put that in was it was a bit too
> self-referential but also I thought, ‘I’m spoiling the TV-movie if I
> do that.'”*
>
> <sub><sup>[Doctor Who: Half Human or All Time Lord?](http://www.tor.com/2015/12/14/doctor-who-half-human-or-all-time-lord/)</sup></sub>

Comment: Gallifreyan just means he's from the planet Gallifrey, in the same way being an Earthling means you're from Earth. You don't have to be an Earthling to be a human, and you don't have to be Gallifreyan to be a Timelord. The Doctor's Species is Timelord. Although, as much as I hate Moffat, I can't deny that he seems to have made this whole "Half-Human" hybrid bullcrap canon, so yay, the Doctor is half Timelord, half human after all.

Comment: Never mind, Moffat later said in an interview that the "Hybrid" refers to the pairing of The Doctor and Clara (because that makes sense), so The Doctor is not half anything, he is in fact a pure-blood Timelord.

Comment: @DisturbedNeo [A Metaphor for Doctor Who's Canon-making Process](http://www.healthyandsimple.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/spaghetti_on_the_wall.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Unknown.

The Doctor is NOT Gallifreyan (all other answers are wrong (reads: outdated)).

In the recent episode *The Timeless Children*, we learned that

> a Gallifreyan found a child (The Doctor) on a planet with portal. This child had ability to regenerate. By studying him, Time Lords were created.

The Doctor also didn't know this. That's possibly because either Gallifreyans hid this fact from him/her or the information got lost when his/her memories were wiped (it was also shown in the episode that his memories were wiped countless times).